# Regular expression, how to add front character with end character

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am using Regular Expressions to code the last characters in an SQL statement, for example the operator - e.g if the SQL statement consist of WHERE keyword LIKE 100, then it must search for LIKE. But now I want to add DISTINCT in front of the field name, for example DISTINCT keyword, in the same regex. I am having difficulties with the front character that must be DISTINCT. Ant help please?

```
$operator = preg_match("/(^DISTINCT\s)\s(NOT|LIKE|NOT LIKE|\<|\>|\!\=)$/", $field, $matches);

$oplength = strlen($matches[0]);

    if(strpos($field, $matches[0])) {
        $field = trim(substr($field, 0, -$oplength));
    }
    else {
        $matches[0] = '=';
    }
```

Comment: Do you want an optional group? `(?:DISTINCT\s+)?`?

Comment: No not optional, DISTINCT must be included but as in front of the field/keyword

Comment: With `preg_match`, you may extract some texts or pieces of texts from larger texts, or you may validate some string input. What are you trying to achieve? Please add a sample string and expected output.

Comment: Here is an example `SELECT DISTINCT products WHERE  user_id NOT LIKE 6`. The regex `/\s(NOT|LIKE|NOT LIKE|\<|\>|\!\=)$/`, covers the word after the field. But now I want the expression to look for the word DISTINCT in front of the field. I am using PCRE regex, and my aim is to create SQL queries and put back-ticks around the field names, and exclude the SQL query words like SUM, DISTINCT, LIKE, NOT etc

Comment: What do you mean by *covers the word after the field*? The regex [does not match the string](https://regex101.com/r/LlUH1R/1). I understand you want to do something that regex are weak at: parsing SQL grammar with a single regex. Look, [this one](https://regex101.com/r/LlUH1R/2) looks helpful, but you will find out it is not that great in other contexts.

Comment: I mean it makes provision for the keyword, eg `NOT`, to be included. It already does it's job there, for the end of the string. Now I just want to add `DISTINCT` for the beginning of the string. I looked at your example - you misunderstood, I only want the field names in back-ticks, not the SQL clauses. It must read as `SELECT DISTINCT 'field' FROM 'Table' WHERE 'user_id' = '6'`

Comment: Sorry, I am afraid I can't help more, just note that `(^DISTINCT\s)\s` matches `DISTINCT` at the start of string and then 2 whitespace chars are required after it. Maybe you need to remove one `\s`.

Comment: I edited my previous comment, have a look. Even with the \s ommitted it is wrong, which is why I came here for help. I am not sure how to insert the regex for in front, I am having difficulties with that

Comment: All I want to know is how to add the DISTINCT string to search for in front of the regex string. Don't worry about the rest, just want to know to add how to match DISTINCT in front'

Comment: Use a separate regex call, `/^DISTINCT\b/`.

Comment: So you mean I must put it in a different regex? I can't use it in my current one? Is there no way that I can just add a word in my current regex to include a word in front?

Comment: You might probably want to try `/^DISTINCT\b.*\s(NOT(?:\s+LIKE)?|LIKE|[<>]|!=)$/`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it is not working how I want. The one you gave me only matches the keyword if `NOT` or `LIKE` etc are included. What if there is no `LIKE` etc? So it is not working. but thanks anyway.

Comment: It is exactly the same as yours, just with `^DISTINCT\b.*` added. Just the alternatives are rearranged so that `NOT LIKE` could get matched if `NOT LIKE` is present, not just `NOT`.

Comment: Doesn't work when I use regex101, but thanks anyway dude.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to have several examples of input and expected matches. Something like `input: "SELECT ... Foo Bar"` `expected match: SELECT`... several examples with various use cases.